# Reactor 3.x - limit the time of a groupBy Flux

Tags: project-reactor

is there any way to force a Flux generated by groupBy() to complete after a period of time (or similarly, limit the maximum # of "open" groups) regardless of the completeness of the upstream?  I have something like the following:

```
Flux<Foo> someFastPublisher;

someFastPublisher
  .groupBy(f -> f.getKey())
  .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) // rate limit each group
  .flatMap(g -> g) // unwind the group
  .subscribe()
;
```

and am running into the case where the Flux hangs, assumed because the number of groups is greater than the `flatMap`'s concurrency.  I could increase the `flatMap` concurrency, but there's no easy way to tell what the max possible size is.  Instead, i know the `Foo`'s being grouped by `Foo.key` are going to be close to each other in time/publication order and would rather use some sort of time window on the groupBy Flux vs. flatMap concurrency (and ending up w/ two different groups w/ the same `key()` isn't a big deal).

I'm guessing the `groupBy` Flux's won't onComplete until `someFastPubisher` onCompletes - i.e. the Flux's handed off to `flatMap` just stay "open" (although they're not likely to ever get a new event).

I am able to work around this either by prefetching `Integer.MAX` in the groupBy or `Integer.MAX`ing the concurrency - but is there a way to control the "life" of the group?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes: you can apply a `take(Duration)` to the groups in order to ensure they close early and a new group with the same key will open after that:

```
source.groupBy(v -> v.intValue() % 2)
      .flatMap(group -> group
              .take(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
              .count()
              .map(c -> "group " + group.key() + " size = " + c)
      )
      .log()
      .blockLast();
```

Comment: i'll trust this works considering who answered it :) but i'm having a hard time visualizing what's going on.  Does `take()` cause the groupedBy Flux to onComplete after Duration?  And/or how is that signaled upstream to the GroupedFlux?

Comment: never mind - i think i get it.  It's not that upstream groupBy is signaled - it's that the flatMap is seeing the `take()` Flux (copy) and not the GroupedFlux Flux

Comment: I would rather have `groupBy` method that takes `Duration` argument as a syntactic sugar. It is hard to come to this approach without a hint.