# Ordered data with Flux.groupBy, replace take(Duration.ofMillis) with e.g. takeUntil

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

Given the below code where I'm using Flux `groupBy` and `.take(Duration.ofMillis(10))`, I can process like 50K records per second. In tests on localhost with `Flux.just`, I can set the delay value to 1 ms and get 500K records through per second, but I don't dare to do that in production.

Data is coming from a database (BigQuery) sorted by the field to group by. Is there a way to avoid using `.take(Duration.ofMillis(10))` with it's fixed delay and use e.g. `takeUntil` instead?

```
data class IncomingDto(
    val aggregation: Aggregation,
    val municipalityId: String,
    val personId: String,
    val startDate: LocalDate,
    val endDate: LocalDate? = null,
)

data class ResultDto(
    val aggregation: Aggregation,
    val municipalityId: String,
    val itemCount: Int,
)

fun reduceResult(
    someDtoFlux: Flux<IncomingDto>
): Flux<ResultDto> = someDtoFlux
    .groupBy { it.aggregation } // it is grouped by 4 fields in my prod code
    .flatMap { groupFlux ->
        groupFlux
            .take(Duration.ofMillis(10)) // https://stackoverflow.com/a/47906950/14072498
            .collectList()
            .mapNotNull { currentSomeDtoList ->
                // some reducing here

                // mock result
                ResultDto(
                    aggregation = currentSomeDtoList.first().aggregation,
                    municipalityId = currentSomeDtoList.first().municipalityId,
                    itemCount = 42
                )
            }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but it doesn't seem you use anything from the grouping, and just do some kind of sampling. So maybe you can use a `.buffer()` instead, and then do all the reducing on the list of all items?

Comment: Hi @IgorArtamonov. I left that part out for brevity, `// some reducing here` is using the data. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If and only if* your incoming data is already sorted by key/group/aggregate, then you do **not** need to use grouping. You can then greatly simplify your workflow by splitting your data sequentially using [windowUntilChanged](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#windowUntilChanged-java.util.function.Function-), and do something like this:

```
someDtoFlux
    .windowUntilChanged { it.aggregate }
    .flatMap { groupFlux -> 
        groupFlux
            .collectList()
            .mapNotNull { currentSomeDtoList ->
                // some reducing here

                // mock result
                ResultDto(
                    aggregation = currentSomeDtoList.first().aggregation,
                    municipalityId = currentSomeDtoList.first().municipalityId,
                    itemCount = currentSomeDtoList.size
                )
            }
    }
```

It will mimic this kind of imperative algorithm:

```
var currentValue = input.next()
var currentAccumulator = Accumulator(currentValue)
while (input.hasNext) {
    currentValue = input.next()
    if (currentValue.key == currentAccumulator.key) {
        currentAccumulator.add(currentValue)
    } else {
        output.push(currentAccumulator)
        currentAccumulator = Accumulator(currentValue)
    }
}
```

And here is a full minimal working example:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import kotlin.random.Random

data class IncomingDto(val key: Int, val value: Int)

data class ResultDto(val key: Int, val valueStats: IntSummaryStatistics)

fun sortedIncoming() : Flux<IncomingDto> {
    val seed = Random.Default.nextLong()
    println("SEED: $seed")
    val rand = Random(seed)
    return Flux.push { sink ->
        val nbGroup = rand.nextInt(10, 1_000)
        for (group in 1..nbGroup) {
            val groupCount = rand.nextInt(100, 10_000)
            for (i in 1..groupCount) {
                sink.next(IncomingDto(group, rand.nextInt(1_000)))
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Flux<IncomingDto>.statsOverSortedGroups() : Flux<ResultDto> {
    return windowUntilChanged(IncomingDto::key)
        .flatMap {
            groupFlux ->
            groupFlux.map { ResultDto(it.key, IntSummaryStatistics().apply { accept(it.value) }) }
                .reduce { r1, r2 ->
                    check(r1.key == r2.key)
                    ResultDto(r1.key, r1.valueStats.apply { combine(r2.valueStats) })
                }
        }
}

fun main() {
    // Verify that no duplicate key is found, by referencing encountered keys in a map
    val encounteredKeys = ConcurrentHashMap<Int, Boolean>()
    sortedIncoming()
        .statsOverSortedGroups()
        .doOnNext {
            if (encounteredKeys.put(it.key, true) != null) {
                throw IllegalStateException("DUPLICATE KEY !")
            } else {
                println(it)
            }
        }
        .blockLast()
}
```

**NOTES**:

- This will fully consume a group before emitting the associated result. You can produce intermediate results by splitting each `groupFlux` in chunks/batch using one of the *buffer* or *window* method, or by using *scan*, etc.
- In case your input flow is not ordered by key, then you do not have much choice but to either keep your code as is, and let consumers reconciliate partial results.

Comment: With `.windowUntilChanged`, I manage to get a througput of 800K records per second in tests, this is great. Thanks a lot! BR